# jupyter executables not accessible after pip install on ubuntu

Tags: jupyter

I have installed `jupyter` - but to double check ran the install again:

```
pip install jupyter 
..
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jupyter in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

However there is *no* `jupyter` (or `jupyter-notebook` etc.) on the `$PATH` or anywhere under `/usr`

```
 find /usr -name jupyter
```

Where is it installed?  I am on `ubuntu 16.0.4`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but is your

> PYTHONPATH

correct?

Because it should be installed there :

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

or

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

And if really you struggle with system based python and Jupyter, I think you should install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) instead.

It's the most used, production ready, compartimented python environment.

And it has jupyter built-in.

To finish my argumentation, it's the [recommanded way](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id3)  to install Jupyter.

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` determines where to find `python` *libraries*  - not the `jupyter` executable : the `$PATH` sets that.